# How to find the data direction register given a port address?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avr

I am writing a custom library for Arduino (for example using the ATmega328P). I would like to get the data direction register given an address of the corresponding port address. For example,

```
#include <avr/io.h>
DDRB = get_data_direction_register(PORTB)
```

How can I possibly achieve this?

Comment: Generally questions are not edited to include the solution.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I answered my own question instead. I hope this does not conflict with the community's guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the register map for the ATmega328 the DDR address is always one less than the port address so that is trivial to calculate.

It may not be the same for other Arduino processors. You may need to have a table that is accessed by the processor type - that should be available at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I didn't know you could easily get the address of the DDR from the port that easily. Thanks

Comment: I tested your solution. I am not sure why it is not working as expected `uint8_t get_data_direction_register(volatile uint8_t* port)
{
     // C style implementation
    return (*((volatile uint8_t*) (port - 1U)));
}`

Comment: You should be returning a pointer (uint8_t*), not an integer (uint8_t).